# PHP Deleting tables is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this script to delete table entries that match a certain database field. The issue is that the script adds back the value of another field like it's suppose to. Yet, when it redirects, the other values have not been deleted. I can not seem to figure out the issue, any help is highly appreciated.

There are two tables structured as is

id, username, cvalue 
id, username, pid

What it is suppose to be doing is deleting every entry with the same pid and adding to the cvaule, the adding to cvalue works, but it doesn't delete anything.

Example: 
 
**Table 1**

1 Bob 5 
2 steve 4

**Table 2**

1 Bob A4DC 
2 Bob A4DC 
3 Steve GQ4A 
4 Steve GQ4A 
5 Bob A4DC

And after Bob would run the script, it should be

**Table 1**

1 Bob 8 
2 steve 4

**Table 2**

3 Steve GQ4A 
4 Steve GQ4A

Here is the code

```
require 'connect.php';
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$queryone = "SELECT `cvalue` FROM `tableone` WHERE username='$username'";
$queryrunone = mysql_query($queryone);
$query_assocone = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryrunone);
$querytwo = "SELECT `pid` FROM `tabletwo` WHERE pid='$id'";
$queryruntwo = mysql_query($querytwo);
$query_assoctwo = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryruntwo);
$cvalue = $query_assoc['cvalue'];
$pid = $query_assoctwo['pid'];
$tablequery = mysql_query("
SELECT *, COUNT(1) AS `enteries` FROM `tabletwo` WHERE `pid`='$pid' GROUP BY `pid`
");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tablequery);
$enteries = $row ['enteries'];
$cvalue = $cvalue + $enteries;
$query = "UPDATE `tableone` SET `cvalue`='$cvalue' WHERE `username`='$username'";
mysql_query($query);
$query = "DELETE from `tabletwo` WHERE `pid`=$id";
mysql_query($query);
unset ($_SESSION['id']);
header ('Location: index.php');
```

Edit:

I should have mentioned that when I $id it is grabbing the id from the previous page which already equals the pid.

Comment: Have you tried running the commit query after the delete? mysql_query("COMMIT");

Comment: Is the database returning an error that you're not capturing?  are you checking the status of the connection to see if it has thrown an error?

Comment: You have a DELETE statement deleting rows with id=$id but the ids are unique. You'll only delete at most 1 row.

Comment: There's zero error-checking in this code. `mysql_error()`

Comment: SHouldn't $cvalue = $query_assoc['cvalue']; be $cvalue = $query_assocone['cvalue'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$query = "DELETE from `tabletwo` WHERE `pid`='" .mysql_real_escape_string ($id) ."'";
```

Pay attention to  SQL injection techniques. Your code is unsafe.